# Which word would you use for something 'internal' or 'in-house'?

Tags: meaning, word-request

There is a word 'kitchen' in my language, like:

- It is their internal kitchen - in this case, 'kitchen' means something we don't care or we should not be aware of, since it is their business and we are good with it

Does it have the same meaning or usage in English?

For example:

- politics kitchen
- management kitchen
- What about them? No worries, they know their business, it's their kitchen

Comment: *Baggage*? *Concern*?

Comment: No, it doesn't have the same meaning. There is an expression "It's not my pigeon", meaning not my responsibility or area of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"wheelhouse" is a similar word.

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wheelhouse)
(Canada, US, figurative) A person's area of authority or expertise.
Synonym: domain
*Horse viruses are in Pat’s wheelhouse.*

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wheelhouse?s=t)
in one’s wheelhouse,
within one’s area of expertise or interest:
*There are some subjects that are in your wheelhouse and some that are not.*

However, it's usually limited to the preposition "in."  You would not say:
politics wheelhouse *
management wheelhouse *

And it's also a somewhat quirky expression that some listeners might not be familiar with.

Another saying:
"We should stay out of it. *Too many cooks spoil the broth.*"

Putting aside figurative words, there are more standard choices:
"That's their specialization / specialty / area of expertise / domain of expertise / job."
"They are experts / gurus / professionals / very knowledgeable."

"So, let them worry about it. It's not our business."

However, none of this matches "kitchen" in an exact one-to-one translation.